# Writing Python lists to columns in csv

Tags: python, list, csv

I have 5 lists, all of the same length, and I'd like to write them to 5 columns in a CSV. So far, I can only write one to a column with this code:

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for val in test_list:
        writer.writerow([val])
```

If I add another `for` loop, it just writes that list to the same column. Anyone know a good way to get five separate columns?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Change them to rows:

```
rows = zip(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5)
```

Then just:

```
import csv

with open(newfilePath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: I got something like: array([-23.], dtype=float32), array([-0.39999986], dtype=float32... how get pure values without types?

Comment: Thanks Joran! This helped me a lot, because I am not able to use Pandas.

Comment: Ok, this way its pretty "simple". What could i do if there is a bunch of lists with 1...n endings. Is there a way to combine zip and a loop threw all of the lists?

Answer (score 36):

The following code writes python lists into columns in csv

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = ['f', 'g', 'i', 'j']
d = [list1, list2]
export_data = zip_longest(*d, fillvalue = '')
with open('numbers.csv', 'w', encoding="ISO-8859-1", newline='') as myfile:
      wr = csv.writer(myfile)
      wr.writerow(("List1", "List2"))
      wr.writerows(export_data)
myfile.close()
```

The output looks like this

[image]

Comment: For python 2.7 use from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest and newline=''" will throw error for python 2.7 . To avoid this error , open the file in 'wb' mode instead of 'w' mode. This will eliminate the need for newline

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, you can do this with Pandas. The benefits include seamless access to specialized methods and row / column labeling:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
list3 = [7, 8, 9]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*[list1, list2, list3]))).add_prefix('Col')

df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

print(df)

   Col0  Col1  Col2
0     1     4     7
1     2     5     8
2     3     6     9
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to combine your lists, and then iterate them

```
for val in itertools.izip(l1,l2,l3,l4,l5):
    writer.writerow(val)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `itertools.izip()` doesn't exist in Python 3.x, and the `zip()` built-in gives an iterator, so that is a drop-in replacement. Also note that if you have a list of lists, you can use the unpacking operator (`zip(*lists)`). This is better design than having variables `l1`, `l2`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to import anything other than csv, and all my lists have the same number of items. The top answer here seems to make the lists into one row each, instead of one column each. Thus I took the answers here and came up with this:

```
import csv
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = ['f', 'g', 'i', 'j','k']
with open('C:/test/numbers.csv', 'wb+') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile)
    wr.writerow(("list1", "list2"))
    rcount = 0
    for row in list1:
        wr.writerow((list1[rcount], list2[rcount]))
        rcount = rcount + 1
    myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add to this one- because quite frankly, I banged my head against it for a while - and while very new to python - perhaps it will help someone else out.

```
 writer.writerow(("ColName1", "ColName2", "ColName"))
                 for i in range(len(first_col_list)):
                     writer.writerow((first_col_list[i], second_col_list[i], third_col_list[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
dic = {firstcol,secondcol} #dictionary
csv = open('result.csv', "w") 
for key in dic.keys():
    row ="\n"+ str(key) + "," + str(dic[key]) 
    csv.write(row)
```

Comment: Your contribution would be more meaningful if you would include some explanation about why this approach should work and be an improvement over what has already been proposed and accepted as the answer.