# Write python dictionary to CSV columns: keys to first column, values to second

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm looking for a way to write a python dictionary to columns (keys in first column and values in second). This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704244/writing-python-lists-to-columns-in-csv) shows how to write a list to a column, but am wondering if there is a way to do this without converting my dictionary to two zipped lists.

```
myDict = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}

keyList = myDict.keys()
valueList = myDict.values()

rows = zip(keyList, valueList)

with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

desired result:

```
1;a
2;b
3;c
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could simply do in python 2.X :

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in myDict.iteritems():
        writer.writerow(row)
```

For python 3.X, change the for loop line to `for row in myDict.items():`

Answer (score 3):

A slightly shorter version is to do:

```
rows = myDict.iteritems()
```

(Or `.items()` for Python 3.)

To get the `;` separator, pass `delimiter` to `csv.reader` or `csv.writer`. In this case:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
```

Comment: This would yield `1;2;3\na;b;c`, not the desired output.

Comment: THANK YOU! It took me forever to find a suitable answer to this you helped me find my solution: `with open('manifesttest2.csv', "wb") as f:
      writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
      writer.writerow(amazonData)`

Comment: @MichaelRomrell CSV's reader and writer objects should be using `,` as a delimiter by default (CSV stands for comma-separated values). Does it work without passing the parameter?