# creating a list with a list as values

Tags: python, list, csv, indexing

I have a small question. I'm trying to create a csv with two columns (ID and Coordinates) where the coordinates column is actually a list of 4 coordinates. Here's my code:

```
North = 42.02
South = 32.40
West = -124.453125
East = -114.0985107421875

difference = (North-South)
divided = 10

splitsize = difference/divided

coordinates = []
ID = []

count = 0

while count < 10:
    coordinates.append([West, South+(splitsize*(count+1)), East, South+(splitsize*(count))])
    ID.append(count+1)
    count += 1
```

Now I want to put both lists into one so when I export it I have a CSV with two columns. IDs in the first and coordinates in the second.

```
1,[-124.453125, 33.362, -114.0985107421875, 32.4]
2,[-124.453125, 34.324, -114.0985107421875, 33.362]
```

The way I've been doing it, I keep getting everything on one row with ID AND coordinates in one cell.

**EDIT**
Just wanted to clarify what I was looking for:
[end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chZqo.png)

**EDIT2: SOLUTION**
This is what I ended up doing from [Writing Python lists to columns in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704244/writing-python-lists-to-columns-in-csv)

```
with open('test.csv', 'wb') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   rows = zip(ID, coordinates)
   for row in rows:
       writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: You should re-name your constants `NORTH`, `SOUTH`, etc. Title-case is reserved for class names in Python

Comment: You should consider using `JSON`, you don't want to be putting data structures into your csvs

Comment: Also, don't use while-loops: `for count in range(10)` is much easier

Comment: Delimit lists with something unique... in NLP we tend to use `|`, so a list of lists `[[a,b,c], [d,e,f], ...]` might be comma-delimited for each element in each sublist and pipe delimited for each sublist... `a,b,c|d,e,f|...`.

Comment: erip, how would I go about pipe delimiting?

Comment: Just like I showed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct for your situation, but a csv by default will return something similar to this since it is a comma-separated file. Try to open the document in Excel and do the following:

1) Select the column of data

2) Under Data, Data Tools, select Text to Columns

3) In that box that opens, choose the "Delimeted" radio button, then next

4) Check the "Comma" box and hit finish.

If your data is now in two columns then what you were seeing was just due to it being a csv file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply William. The problem with this is that the coordinates get split up because they have commas between them.

Comment: I understand that, but I guess what I'm saying is these two columns aren't REALLY being joined into one column. It just appears that way because you're saving it as a .csv file. If you were to output it as an .xlsx file would it still be in one column?

Comment: Yeah it does :\

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to put both lists into one so when I export it I have a CSV
>   with two columns. IDs in the first and coordinates in the second.
>
> 1,[-124.453125, 33.362, -114.0985107421875, 32.4] 2,[-124.453125,
>   34.324, -114.0985107421875, 33.362]

The square brackets are not part of csv syntax, so this will be imported as

```
"1","[-124.453125", "33.362", "-114.0985107421875", "32.4]"
```

The simplest solution, if you control the consumer of this csv,  is to just export five values and have the consumer deal with the columns. 
If you need to have a hierarchical structure, JSON is probably a better bet.

If your consumer expects a list as the second column and cannot cope with JSON (???) then you'd want to export something like

```
1,"[-124.453125, 33.362, -114.0985107421875, 32.4] 2,[-124.453125,
34.324, -114.0985107421875, 33.362]"
```

and then hope that the consumer does an `eval` or something similar to turn this into a list. Note that this is a really bad idea, since `eval` executes arbitrary code with the user's privileges, so any naive implementation of this (and most clever implementations as well) will be nice attack vectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
North = 42.02
South = 32.40
West = -124.453125
East = -114.0985107421875

difference = (North-South)
divided = 10

splitsize = difference/divided

my_list=[]
count = 1

while count < 10:
    coordinates = []
    coordinates.extend([West, South+(splitsize*(count+1)), East, South+(splitsize*(count))])
    ID=count
    my_list.append([ID,coordinates])
    count += 1
```