# Writing python list to a google sheet as a column

Tags: python, gspread

Lets say I have 3 columns in my Google Spreadsheet named "First Name","Last Name" and "ID",
And I have 3 python lists, the first one is a list of names, the second list of last names and third list contains IDs.

So I want to insert list1 under "First Name" column, list2 under "Last Name" column etc.

here is the picture of what I want to do

[image: https://imgur.com/a/g6UrNv1]

Comment: Try using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704244/writing-python-lists-to-columns-in-csv, and see if it helps you.

Comment: Q is referring to google sheets @the_redcar

Comment: In that case, you can try following the directions stated in https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/read-write-google-sheets-python/ and loop through your lists.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the three lists into rows by writing: `r = zip(list1,list2,list3)`.
Then use the following to write the lists.

```py
import csv

with open(newfilePath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

This code works if you are using a CSV excel file. If you using XLS, then this code will not work.

Since you are using Google Sheets, try this instead: makeuseof.com/tag/read-write-google-sheets-python

Comment: Please mark as correct answer if this helped! :)