# writting lists to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have 4 lists of items I want to write to a csv file. currently I am able to write  one list under a header1. How do I append the rest of 3 lists I have to the csv , say list 2 under header2, list3 under header3 and list4 under header 4?

Please help~~

this is my code:

```
    def write_to_csv(list_of_ec2s):
        with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

            writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = '\n')
            writer.writerow(['Header1','Header2','Header3','Header4'])
            writer.writerow(list1)
    
    write_to_csv(list1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing Python lists to columns in csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704244/writing-python-lists-to-columns-in-csv)

Comment: yeah, I used Ashok Kumar Jayaraman on that link to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv 
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [4,5,6]
list3 = [7,8,9]
data = [ ['Header1','Header2','Header3','Header4'] ,list1,list2,list3]
with open('hello.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f) 
    writer.writerows(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps